# how can i navigate one form method to another form?

Tags: ionic3

I am new in ionic 3. How can I navigate one form method to another form? I take two forms named Home and MyFamily. In my family home page is navigated using navCtrl and now I want to call one method `Editmethod` of Home page is in MyFamily form  so how can I call the method of home page in MyFamily page.

when I try the below error will be displayed.

[image]

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Items } from '../../providers/providers';
import { PostProvider } from '../../providers/post/post';
import { LaunchNavigator, LaunchNavigatorOptions } from '@ionic-
native/launch-navigator';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { partition } from 'rxjs/operator/partition';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../../pages/home/home';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-myfamily',
templateUrl: 'myfamily.html',
})
export class MyfamilyPage {
paralist = {};
modalheader: string;
showData = [];
btnTableDataFirst = [];
currentItems: any = [];
horBtnData = [];
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public navParams: NavParams,
public items: Items, public _ps: PostProvider,private home:HomePage,
private launchNavigator: LaunchNavigator,public toastCtrl: ToastController) 
{}

btnHorClick(partyName, id, obj) {
this.showData = this.horBtnData['table' + id];
this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {
  param1: JSON.stringify(obj)
});
this.goCam();
}
goCam(){
this.home.editdata();
}
ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad MyfamilyPage');
  this.GetHorizontalBtnData();
}

  GetHorizontalBtnData() {
  let paralist = {};
  paralist['searchText'] = 'vpravinchandra@gmail.com';
  paralist['corpcode'] = 'Email';
  console.log(paralist)
  this._ps.postData(paralist, 'Search')
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.horBtnData = data;
      this.btnTableDataFirst = data['table'];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.btnTableDataFirst.length; i++) {
      }
      console.log(this.horBtnData)
    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please post some of your code and provide a [mcve]

Comment: please dont post error as an image.. paste the text instead